# Start or stop mysql database using java programming

Tags: java, mysql

I am having multiple mysql databases running on multiple servers.In hsql database we can start the server or stop the server using java programming.I am going to use any database at any time so I want to start the mysql database server or stop it using java programming.
Is there any way to start or stop the mysql database using java programming?

Comment: For security reasons is not a good idea to manipulate server processes directly from java code.What platform you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Try this in windows machine:

**START**

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net START MySQL");
```

**STOP**

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net STOP MySQL");
```

Comment: @shashankaholic MySQL within Xampp is not stopping in this way. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a linux system, you can invoke the database init script using java. They are usually located in `/etc/init.d/mysql[d]` ond BSD variants it is found in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/`. I am not sure how this work in Windows environments.

You have to ensure that your user which is running the process is allowed to execute this scripts.

Comment: In Windows, MySQL can run as service with any random name (or run as application with any random name).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Well i have seen it by 'MySQL' everytime.Anyways, we can find the name with task manager.