# How to stop wscript.exe from java to stop a mysql server?

Tags: java, vbscript, cmd, command

I am trying to stop wscript that was started from a java application using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("") method.I started a mysql server using wscript.But wscript is not closing when I close my java application,because of this when I restart my application every time 80% of memory is filled with wscript.exe making my pc slow.
So my question is how to safely close wscript.exe after its use is over.If this question was asked before someone please point me in right direction

```
 public void startMySQLServer() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Shersha\\\\\\\\Documents\\\\\\\\NetBeansProjects\\\\\\\\Berries\\\\\\\\batch\\\\\\\\mysql_start.vbs");
            System.out.println("waiting to start mysql server");
            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("mysql server started sucessfully");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataBaseManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

EDITED

```
public void stopMySQLServer() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Shersha\\\\\\\\Documents\\\\\\\\NetBeansProjects\\\\\\\\Berries\\\\\\\\batch\\\\\\\\mysql_stop.vbs");
            System.out.println("waiting to stop mysql server");
            process.waitFor();
            process.destroy();
            System.out.println("process exit value" + process.exitValue());
            System.out.println("mysql server stopped sucessfully");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataBaseManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

EDITED 2
mysql_start.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
  " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
  Wscript.Quit
  End if
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\Users\Shersha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Berries\batch\mysql_start.bat",0,True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a valid instance of Process, you should be able to call `process.destroy();`

> Solution used came from duplicate question listed below;
>
> [@shashankaholic Answer to Start or stop mysql database using java programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991357/692942)
>
> ---
>
> **START**
>
> ```
> Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net START MySQL");
> ```
>
> **STOP**
>
> ```
> Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net STOP MySQL");
> ```

Comment: when I start mysql_start.vbs a cmd windows also starts.will  destroy can make cmd window to close?

Comment: As the CMD window is only a graphical representation of your process, it should close once the process is terminated. But you will have to give this a try.

Comment: Ok let me try it if it works i will accept this answer and upvote :)

Comment: I have tried this but wscript.exe does not close,nor the console window host,and windows command processor it just keep on accumulating in the memory .I have added a screen shot to make it clear.

Comment: when you call process.destroy() do you get any error? When you call process.exitValue() what is the return value?

Comment: Nope i don't get any error

Comment: Let me check process.exitValue()

Comment: I am getting process exit value as 0.

Comment: alternatively: you execute a script called `mysql_start.vbs` is there a `mysql_stop.vbs`script you could execute?

Comment: Actually i have mysql_stop.vbs script also.Edited above.as you said i have added destroy to all process that i start

Comment: ok i found fllowing answer. perhaps this can help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990788/start-or-stop-mysql-database-using-java-programming

Comment: I think i found the problem i have another vbscript inside mysql_start.vbs

Comment: Thanks a lot now i am able to start mysql server and stop it with out the need of any script :)

Comment: I have also edited the question and answer to make sense :)

Comment: @ShershaFn No what you did was copy from an existing answer without attribution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9991357/692942, if the other answer helped, go to that up-vote it and move on.

Comment: Ok i will do that thanks for correcting me :)