# netbeans java check if local services is running progammingly

Tags: java, mysql

I have n Netbeans Java project that connects to the MYSQL, to read data from my database.

But the MYSQL services is not running, and I have to manually start it.
Can I start this service in my code?
[Windows Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyz5e.png)

Comment: Why can't you have it running automatically ?

Comment: [1] Possible duplicate of [Start or stop mysql database using java programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9990788/2985643), (though it seems that the accepted answer is only relevant on Windows platforms). [2] Please remove the **netbeans** tag from your question; the fact that you are using NetBeans is completely irrelevant for what you want to do. [3] Please add a **mysql** tag to your question.

Comment: @jr593 Regarding _Why can't you have it running automatically?_, perhaps the poster does have the service running automatically, but wants to start it as a recovery action. Regardless, the question is legitimate.

Comment: I did make it to run automatically, but if the end user don't know or doesn't set it to automatically, I would like to check the status and start the service if it is not running, before trying to connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the link (Start or stop mysql database using java programming). I did try Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net START MySQL");, but it doen't seem to start the MySQL service.

Comment: @Martin Yes, that wouldn't have worked for at least two reasons: your service is named "MySQL80", not "MySQL", and (for me at least) the call to NET START must be run as an administrator. I posted an answer that might work for you, but even if it does it has some limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is specific to Windows and assumes that the MySQL service name is **MySQL80** (as shown in your screenshot). To start the MySQL service if it is not running from Java in Windows:

- Create a **BAT** file containing nothing but **NET START MySQL80**
- Create a shortcut to that **BAT** file. In Windows File Explorer display the properties of that shortcut, click the **Shortcut** tab, click the **Advanced...** button, and check the **Run as administrator** box:

  [image: asAdmin]
- Run the Java application shown below which will:

  - Check the status of the **MySQL80** service by parsing the output returned by the command **sc query MySQL80**. See method `getServiceState()` in the code below.
  - If the service is not running (because `getServiceState()` returned "STOPPED"), run the shortcut to the BAT file (as an administrator) to start the service. See method `startService()` in the code below, and set your value of `String shortcut` as appropriate.
  - If the service is already running (`getServiceState()` returned "RUNNING"), or the service name is not recognized, the code does nothing.
  - If there is a problem starting the service the error stream is displayed.

This is the code:

```
package servicestarter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ServiceStarter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServiceStarter ss = new ServiceStarter();
        String serviceName = "MySQL80";
        String serviceStatus = ss.getServiceState(serviceName);

        if ("STOPPED".equals(serviceStatus)) {
            System.out.println("Service " + serviceName + " is stopped. Starting the service...");
            String shortcut = "D:\\temp\\netstartmysql80.bat.lnk";
            Process process = ss.startService(shortcut);
            // Display any error output. Should be nothing there if all goes well...
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getServiceState(String serviceName) throws IOException {
    String state = "";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c sc query " + serviceName);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("STATE")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            state = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
            break;
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    return state; // Returns "STOPPED" or "RUNNING", or empty string for invalid service name.
}

private Process startService(String shortcut) throws IOException {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " + shortcut);
}
}
```

Method `getServiceState()` just parses the content produced by **sc query MySQL80** to determine the status ("STATE") of the service:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query MySQL80

SERVICE_NAME: MySQL80
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Notes:

- The above code works for me on Windows 10 starting a MySQL 8.0 service named "**MySQL80**", though it should start any **STOPPED** service by changing the value of `String serviceName`, and the name and content of the shortcut that is run.
- This approach has a problem which may be a deal breaker: because the service must be started as an administrator you will normally get that familiar prompt from **User Account Control** when the shortcut to the **BAT** file is run, asking *"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?"*. You can easily avoid that prompt by running the application from a **Command Prompt** window that was **Run as administrator**, but that may not necessarily be a viable approach for you.
- This is not a robust solution. If the output generated by **SC QUERY {service name}** changes this code may break, but I don't know of a Java API to query Windows services directly.

Comment: @Martin I'm glad it works for you, but a less fragile approach would be to use C++ instead of Java if at all possible, since then you can use the Windows API to query and start the service - no need for hacks such as having an external BAT file, or parsing output. [Microsoft have even provided the C++ source code to do exactly what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Services/starting-a-service)!